# Angular2: Rename component

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I need to rename a component in my Angular2 application. I renamed all the files in the component folder (from *x.component.** to *y.component.**) and the folder itself (from *x* to *y*). I also updated files:

- y.component.ts: renamed templateUrl/styleUrls
- app.routing.ts
- app.module.ts

After that I wanted to restart ng server with 'ng s', but now it says `"You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve command."`

So, is there a "standard protocol" for renaming components in Angular2? Am I forgetting something? Or is it just impossible to do that and the only option is to create a new one, copy everything there, and delete the old one?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you renamed the app.component ?

Comment: No, it was different component, not the main app one :/

Comment: Did you also changed the name of the component in the declarations of the app.modules.ts ?

Comment: I have app.module.ts (singular), yeah, I changed that too (import and declarations). In fact, I searched for the old component's name and x.component in my project and there is none. I wonder what I might have broken...

Comment: Then I don't really know. Did you make sure you executed the commands at the right path ?

Comment: Yeah, that's weird )) Thank you for your time! I guess I will just roll back and try again...

Comment: Then I wish you good luck :)

Comment: Thanks! :)  I created a new component and copied everything from the old one. It works. I probably just messed up something while renaming it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not 100% sure about the problem youre having but i got that message too after cloning from github. 
Im going to assume you have the angular-cli and node.js installed, so cd into the root directory of your project and type

```
ng init
```

this worked for me, i havent a clue why but my guess is that by moving things around or changing them makes the cli confused and it ends up ignoring the project. Hope this works for you!